# How to set up a configuration of LDAP in a Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, ldap

I am new to use LDAP, and should set up LDAP in a Laravel project that stores users' information. So I have used the following library below and experienced some troubles.

https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel

1) Can I test LDAP on localhost? (without any domains) The following setting does not work.

```
        $config = [

            // Mandatory Configuration Options

            'domain_controllers'    => ['corp.localhost'],
            'base_dn'               => 'dc=localhost',
            'admin_username'        => 'username',
            'admin_password'        => 'password'

]
```

2) What is the relation between DB and LDAP?

For example, the facade below is affected by both 'User' table on DB and 'User' information on LDAP?

```
use Adldap\Laravel\Facades\Adldap;

// Finding a user.
$user = Adldap::search()->users()->find('john doe');

// Searching for a user.
$search = Adldap::search()->where('cn', '=', 'John Doe')->get();

// Authenticating against your LDAP server.
if (Adldap::auth()->attempt($username, $password)) {
    // Passed!
}

// Running an operation under a different connection:
$users = Adldap::getProvider('other-connection')->search()->users()->get();

// Creating a user.
$user = Adldap::make()->user([
    'cn' => 'John Doe',
]);

$user->save();
```

I have searched for many on google and but they are only theories... AND I must be deeply misunderstood for LDAP. Is that Laravel library only for a client side and I should set up a LDAP server on another location? **My destination is setting up a storage of Users' information on Synology Nas using the LDAP**.(I do not know why I should use LDAP. DB can also save users' information..)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't use LDAP in a web system if there is not an LDAP server already being used which you are forced, coerced and tortured to use :) If you can, avoid using LDAP.

Having said that, in this small tutorial you will find how to test your LDAP connections and how to set up an *adminless* LDAP auth system in Laravel 5:

[laravel-simple-ldap-auth](https://github.com/jotaelesalinas/laravel-simple-ldap-auth)

You will have to ask your IT administrator for the real connection data of your production LDAP server.